# The role of preposition "over" here?

Tags: prepositions

1. He ruled **over a great empire.**
2. He ruled **a great empire.**

I don't think not including over makes any difference,but don't understand **what is the role of "over" here?**

Comment: By "role" do you mean its grammatical role, or its semantic role - ie what difference does it make to the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @JamesK   yes, both semantically and grammatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb "rule" may optionally take a direct object. The semantic role of the object is the patient, it the thing that is acted upon by the agent.

Alternately the verb "rule" may be used intransitively.  In the intransitive sense it can be followed by adverbs or prepostitional phrases that give some more information about how, why, when or where someone ruled:  "He ruled magnificently" or "He ruled from London".  One possible prepostional phrase is "over {something}" and in this case the {something}" is the thing that is ruled, that is it the thing that is acted on by by the verb "rule".

So there is no real difference in meaning, between "He ruled" and "He ruled over".  The two different expressions end up with more-or-less the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The role of "over" is to emphasize the territory ruled or the subjects in that territory.  As @James K explained, both can be used, especially since the object is generic ("a great empire").

But I think the is a semantic difference when the object is concrete and the emphasis is in **how** / **when** he rules, where the *second* form is preferred.  For example:

> "He ruled the Roman empire wisely"

or

> "Septimius Severus ruled the Roman Empire for 18 years".

When the emphasis is in **where**, the *first* form is preferred.  For example:

> "Alexander the Great ruled over an empire covering more than two million square miles."